# Integrated cordova-plugin-applepay in cordova project but payment is not getting success, Used same code from cordova

Tags: cordova, applepay, integrate

Having issue with implementing ApplePay in Cordova project. Installed the plugin "cordova-plugin-applepay" and followed the same instructions to make test Payment when running on the simulator the payment getting failed and getting "'My Fashion Company' was not able to complete the payment. Please try again"

Used the below plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-applepay and change the config as mentioned in this plugin website and then use the sample code (on the above website) to make the test payment.

I already created the merchant ID on apple developer and the certificate configs.

The below code I have implemented to make the the payment using apple pay:

```
ApplePay.makePaymentRequest(
{
  items: [
      {
          label: '3 x Basket Items',
          amount: 49.99
      },
      {
          label: 'Next Day Delivery',
          amount: 3.99
      },
              {
          label: 'My Fashion Company',
          amount: 53.98
      }
  ],
  shippingMethods: [
      {
          identifier: 'NextDay',
          label: 'NextDay',
          detail: 'Arrives tomorrow by 5pm.',
          amount: 3.99
      },
      {
          identifier: 'Standard',
          label: 'Standard',
          detail: 'Arrive by Friday.',
          amount: 4.99
      },
      {
          identifier: 'SaturdayDelivery',
          label: 'Saturday',
          detail: 'Arrive by 5pm this Saturday.',
          amount: 6.99
      }
  ],
  supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'masterCard', 'discover'],
  merchantCapabilities: ['3ds', 'debit', 'credit'],          
  merchantIdentifier: 'using my merchant Id',
  currencyCode: 'GBP',
  countryCode: 'GB',
  billingAddressRequirement: 'none',
  shippingAddressRequirement: 'none',
  shippingType: 'shipping'
}).then((paymentResponse) => {
  // The user has authorized the payment.

  // Handle the token, asynchronously, i.e. pass to your merchant bank to
  // action the payment, then once finished, depending on the outcome:

  // Here is an example implementation:

  // MyPaymentProvider.authorizeApplePayToken(token.paymentData)
  //    .then((captureStatus) => {
  //        // Displays the 'done' green tick and closes the sheet.
  //        ApplePay.completeLastTransaction('success');
  //    })
  //    .catch((err) => {
  //        // Displays the 'failed' red cross.
  //        ApplePay.completeLastTransaction('failure');
  //    });
}).catch((e) => {
  // Failed to open the Apple Pay sheet, or the user cancelled the payment.`enter code here`
})
```

After make the payment it should complete the payment. Am I missing something over here?